# Force Coq to simplify unfalsifiable pattern matches

Tags: functional-programming, coq

I'm running through [logic foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html#lab54) and during the `lower_grade_lowers` exercise, Coq is behaving in a way that I wouldn't expect.

I have the following goal:

```
  grade_comparison match l with
                   | A | _ => Grade l Natural
                   end (Grade l Plus) = Lt
```

This, to me, feels like it should simplify: the `| A | _ => ...` branch is not falsifiable, and I would expect Coq to simplify the whole thing to:

```
grade_comparison (Grade l Natural) (Grade l Plus) = Lt
```

This does not happen, and I do not understand why...

Comment: Maybe because `Grade l Natural` is guarded behind a match; did you try running `destruct l.` at this point?